# Testcase using NUnit

Tags: nunit

Folks, I am new to writing testcases for the methods. Here I have a InsertMethod for which I want to write testcase using NUnit testing framework.  Help me in writing the testcase for the method below :

public bool insertUser(String FirstName, String LastName)
    {
        bool result = false;

```
    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand();

    try
    {
        myconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=BABU-PC;Initial Catalog=contacts;Integrated Security=True";

        myconn.Open();

        mycmd.Connection = myconn;
        mycmd.CommandText = "InsertUser";
        mycmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter();
        param1.ParameterName = "@FirstName";
        param1.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
        param1.Size = 8000;
        param1.Value = FirstName;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add(param1);


        SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
        param2.ParameterName = "@LastName";
        param2.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
        param2.Size = 8000;
        param2.Value = LastName;
        mycmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

        int i = 0;

        i = mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }


    }

    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message.ToString());

        return false;
    }

    finally
    {
        mycmd.Dispose();
        myconn.Close();
        myconn = null;

    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks

SBM

Comment: so you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. Don't think about your existing code. Think about what you want to test. So what would you like to test?

Comment: Unit testing is not very good for database related tasks.

Comment: Because there are multiple paths through the code, you will need multiple test cases to test fully.

Answer (score 1):

Cellfish is right. Don't think about the code, think about what the method is supposed to do. Without even looking at your code, I'd do this kind of test:

1- Preparation

```
lastName = "LastName"
firstName = "FirstName"
```

Then try to fetch a user with firstName and lastName and make sure that it's not already there.

2- Execute

```
InsertUser(firstName, lastName)
```

3- Check

- Make sure InsertUser return true
- Try to fetch a user with firstName and lastName and make sure that it is there with the correct values.

Comment: This tests the 'true' return path. To test the 'false' path, attempt to insert a user that is already in the database.